# Understanding a piece of Perl code

Tags: perl, komodo

I have never done perl programming but I am looking at following Perl code and it confused me:

```
sub read_pds
{
   my $bin_s;
   my $input_pds_file = $_[0];
  open(my $fh, '<', $input_pds_file) or die "cannot open file $input_pds_file";
  {
    local $/;
    $bin_s = <$fh>;
  }
  close($fh);
  return $bin_s;
}
```

I am looking at the code above and though that it will not return any value since there is no return type defined there.

But at the bottom it is returning a value. Now How would I know what is the type of the value since it does not show any value when I add watch on it using Komodo..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first argument passed to function call:

```
my $input_pds_file = $_[0];
```

Open file to read:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $input_pds_file) or die "cannot open file $input_pds_file";
```

Sets input record separator to none (default is new line sequence: CR or LF or CRLF):

```
local $/;
```

And read whole file to variable:

```
$bin_s = <$fh>;
```

Why read whole file at once? Because "diamond operator": <> read data from handle until find input record separator (which is cleared above).

And finally, returns one big string:

```
return $bin_s;
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl doesn't have types as you're thinking of them, but the returned value will be a string (the contents of `$input_pds_file`. The `<$fh>` reads a single line/record from `$fh`, and because `$/` (the input record separator) is set to `undef`, that will be the whole file.

Comment: So it will return whole file and return a string? I am not sure how the contents of this file looks like because it has extension .pds but should it not be Byte[]?

Comment: @Californicated what you call a `Byte[]`, perl calls a string.

Comment: ohk. I am sorry for misunderstanding.